# Combining Rotation and Translation

Tags: opengl, matrix, rotation, translation

I have a scene in OpenGL, which is rotated and translated, and I would like to translate it further along its OWN Z axis. How should I reflect this ?

To be a bit more concrete:
glTranslated (tx,ty,tz)
gpRotated (rx,1,0,0)
gpRotated (ry,0,1,0)
gpRotated (rz,0,0,1)

What modification should I bring to the tx,ty,tz in order to translate the scene toward its own Z axis (which for the "camera" may be the X axis ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should modify the model matrix with an additional `glTranslate()`. The model transformation is independent of the camera, so you can do all you want there. Just make sure to place the model in world space at the end and then use a view matrix which works in world-space (i.e. transforms world->camera space.)

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. However being a newbie in OpenGL, could you please let me know how I can "place the model in world space at the end and then use a view matrix which works in world-space" ? As I would like to use the model's own axis, shouldn't I put it in the model space rather ? Thanks !

Comment: Think of the first bunch of the transformations working in the local (model) coordinate space, rotating the model as you wish. When you are done, you want to place the model somewhere in the scene, so you apply a transformation which moves the vertices from local to world space. It might help you to think about transformations not only as transforming from one space to another, but also to transform vertices relative to another space (i.e. after the rotation, either the space or the object itself has been rotated.)

Comment: I am actually writing a 3d editor where one can move and translate as much as he wants. So does it make sense to thing about recalculating my tx,ty,tz and have only one rotate and one translate for the whole scene, or doesn't make sense ? I any appreciate your help and patience on this.

Comment: Try the math on a paper :) In your case, there's no difference if you apply the three rotations at once or one after the other. Also keep in mind the order your transformations are applied. After you have rotated the object, when you translate along X, you will apply a world-space translation and not an object-local transformation in the rotated-space. For instance, if you want to rotate an object you usually perform (undo-world-space-translation)*(rotation)*(redo world-space-translation) in order to do it in object space.

Comment: I guess I start to get it. However my object is rotated and translated now. I have a function that detects that it should go 10 in direction of Z. If I do translate(0,0,10) of the object in my function, the movement is erratic. So should I undo the world space anyway ? What is the OpenGL function that allows me to do that ? Thank YOU !!

Comment: Having investigated a bit more reveals that the issue is not in my Translation, but in the glUnproject I do to analyze where I clicked. I will open another issue for that. Thanks again for your help !